# Google reCAPTCHA failed for second time on the bootstrap model

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-modal, recaptcha

I have a form with multiple fields & google recaptcha which I open in popup model.For the first time everything work well.

[image]

But when I close popup and try to open popup second time at that time I got error "**Not Found.The requested url was not found on this server**".
[image]

Here is my HTML code:

```
  <div id="RecaptchaField2"></div>
```

Javascript :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var CaptchaCallback = function() {
      if ( $('#RecaptchaField2').length ) {
        grecaptcha.render('RecaptchaField2', {'sitekey' : 
            '6LdG1ioUAAAAANOH2BnJO_5zv0NE2UNZS9jou7Yh'
       });
      }
   }

    $(".inq-button").click(function(){
      setTimeout(function() {
          var script = document.createElement('script');
          script.src = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?
          onload=CaptchaCallback&render=explicit';
          script.type = 'text/javascript';
         document.body.parentNode.appendChild(script);         
     }, 100); 
   });
</script>
```

This problem is torturing me since last week and I still couldn't figure out why it happens.

Would you please give me proper suggestion about this?

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when do you remove the dynamically added recaptcha `script` element?

Comment: @YohanesGultom, I tried to remove script element on the beginning of the 
onclick function.

Comment: have you confirmed that it's working properly? isn't supposed to be done inside the `$(".inq-button").click()` just before you add a new one?

Comment: @YohanesGultom, yes it's working properly first time but second time i got the error.

Comment: Since everything seems in place, I'd suggest you try to create an online script (eg. jsfiddle) to reproduce your error. As an example, I have created a simplified example of google recaptcha within bootstrap modal that works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/vwngn7d0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this script, It will working.

```
<script>
    var CaptchaCallback = function() {
    if ( $('#RecaptchaField1').length ) {
        grecaptcha.render('RecaptchaField1', {'sitekey' : '6LdG1ioUAAAAANOH2BnJO_5zv0NE2UNZS9jou7Yh'
        });
    }
    if ( $('#RecaptchaField2').length ) {
       grecaptcha.render('RecaptchaField2', {'sitekey' : '6LdG1ioUAAAAANOH2BnJO_5zv0NE2UNZS9jou7Yh'
       });
    }
}

var j = 1;

$(".inq-button").click(function(){


   setTimeout(function() {
    if(j){
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=CaptchaCallback&render=explicit';
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      document.body.parentNode.appendChild(script);
 }
 else
 {
    $('#RecaptchaField2').empty();
    removejscssfile("api.js", "js"); //remove all occurences of "somescript.js" on page
    var onloadCallback = function() {

        if ( $('#RecaptchaField2').length ) {
            grecaptcha.render('RecaptchaField2', {'sitekey' : '6LdG1ioUAAAAANOH2BnJO_5zv0NE2UNZS9jou7Yh'
       });


    }
    }; 
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=CaptchaCallback&render=explicit';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.body.parentNode.appendChild(script);
   }

   j = 0;

   }, 100);

   });  


 function removejscssfile(filename, filetype){
    var targetelement=(filetype=="js")? "script" : (filetype=="css")? "link" : "none" //determine element type to create nodelist from
    var targetattr=(filetype=="js")? "src" : (filetype=="css")? "href" : "none" //determine corresponding attribute to test for
    var allsuspects=document.getElementsByTagName(targetelement)
    for (var i=allsuspects.length; i>=0; i--){ //search backwards within nodelist for matching elements to remove
    if (allsuspects[i] && allsuspects[i].getAttribute(targetattr)!=null && allsuspects[i].getAttribute(targetattr).indexOf(filename)!=-1)
    allsuspects[i].parentNode.removeChild(allsuspects[i]) //remove element by calling parentNode.removeChild()
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should need to clear captcha before render is `grecaptcha.reset()`

However, in order for this function to work you have to render the reCaptacha explicitly like this :

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

Comment: @CKG, I already tried with this function to render the reCaptacha explicitly but I got error "Object not found!".